# Full-screen modal without Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, overlay

I was wondering if there were any online resources to creating a fullscreen modal without using Bootstrap. I'd like to learn how to implement this myself. The full effect would be a scrollable overlay for a projects section so if the user wants to view more of a project they can click on the image and a fullscreen box overlays the current page with the ability to close when done.

Comment: Bootstrap just uses its classes and javascript to create a modal.  For what you want to do its simple.  Just bind your click event(or whatever event you wish to open the modal) and create a div or other element that is absolutely or fixed position.  Ensure your hight and widths are set to fill the window and provide a higher z-index than your page content.  Full window modals are clumsy in my opinion but if its what you want, they are pretty easy to create as you don't need any shadow backdrop or centering styles.  Just look at bootstraps modal javascript and see how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you think it would be more useful if the section just went to a new page?

Comment: Yes.  Modals are one of those things that get overused.  It always seems like a good idea until you put it into place.  Modals are best left to small focused bits of information or forms.  And if the modal is implemented incorrectly it can bog down your site and really upset users.  So in the case of a full window modal, I would say go with a new page.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this animatedModal will handle it.

http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/